# Python asyncio: Do I Need Synchronization Primitives for Shared Variables When Using run_in_executor with ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm working with Python's asyncio and triing to understand the run_in_executor function with the default ThreadPoolExecutor to handle blocking tasks asynchronously. My concern is regarding accessing shared variables within these tasks.

My understanding is: When I use run_in_executor with a ThreadPoolExecutor, the tasks are executed in separate threads. Therefore, to ensure thread safety and prevent race conditions, I should use synchronization primitives like locks when accessing shared variables, just as I would with the threading module.

Is my understanding correct, or does asyncio handle shared variables differently in this context?